# How to bring up tooltips in a line chart when the points are on the same point x

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Having a chart type line, where I have drawn points on the same point x with y but different, I should bring up the tooltip on the various points, but unfortunately when I pass with the mouse on the chart appears to me only one of the marks painted on the same x, ignoring the other. The graph is on:
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsd96atf/)
I tried, but unfortunately I have not found anything to solve my problem. And 'possible to bring up the tooltip on all points?
Thank you all for the help.

```
..
```

david

Answer (score 0):

Use scatter serie, instead of line chart.

```
series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        lineWidth: 2,
        name: 'Litri Carburante Rimasti',
        data: data,
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2)
            },
            color: "#000000"
        },
        color: colorerifornimento,
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jsd96atf/2/